# Question on valuation rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

Atiyah & Macdonald - *Commutative Algebra*, p.65.

Let $F$ be a field and $\Omega$ be an algebraically closed field.

Let $\Sigma$ be the collection of all $(A,f)$ such that $A$ is a subring of $F$ and $f:A\rightarrow \Omega$ is a ring homomorphism. We partially order $\Sigma$ as follows:

$$ (A,f)\leq (A',f') \text{ iff } A\subset A', f'\upharpoonright A=f$$

The text asserts that there exists a maximal element of $\Sigma$.

However, shouldn't we need more condition on $\Omega$ so that it has a maximal element? There can be no such pair $(A,f)$ because $\Sigma$ can possibly be the empty set. (This is because we are defining ring homomorphisms to send $1$ to $1$)

What would be a mild condition on $\Omega$ to have $\Sigma$ nonempty?

Comment: If you take for Ω an algebraic closure of $F$ it will be non-empty.

Comment: @Bernard yeah sure, but the author does not restrict it to that case, and he chooses an algebraically closed field which does not contain an isomorphic copy of $F$ as a subring and prove something else. (In this case $\Sigma$ is nonempty though)

Comment: I think that in all cases of interest, $F$ and $\Omega$ will have the same characteristic, and then $\Sigma$ will be non-empty. Atiyah & MacDonald should have stated some requirement on the characteristic, because, for example, if $F = \Bbb{Z}_2$ and $\Omega = \Bbb{C}$, the set of homomorphisms $\Sigma$ is empty and Zorn's lemma is not applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\Sigma$ is nonempty iff either $F$ has characteristic $0$ or $F$ has positive characteristic and $\Omega$ has the same characteristic.  Indeed, if $F$ has characteristic $0$ then $\mathbb{Z}$ is is a subring, and there exists a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to\Omega$.  If $F$ has positive characteristic $p$, then $p=0$ in any subring of $F$ so no subring can map to $\Omega$ unless $\Omega$ also has characteristic $p$.  And if $\Omega$ does have characteristic $p$, then $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a subring of $F$ which has a homomorphism to $\Omega$.